# Realm and react-native, How can I roll the security keys?

Tags: encryption, react-native, realm

To better protect Realm, I would like to roll the security tokens every now and then.

I followed the guide on [how to encrypt](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#encryption), but did not find anywhere how I can change the key to a new one.

Anyone know what might be the best way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Trying to change the encryption key from a DB will make the data unreadable. If you want to do it I think you should perform a migration. Then, in the "new" database, you can use the new encryption key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change an encryption key for an existing Realm. Instead you would need to create a second Realm and copy all objects from the old Realm - you can do this by looping through all object and passing them into `newRealm.create`. You could then call `realm.close()` on each realm and copy the file to the path of the original Realm.